# Resources 404 not found after routing a subpath in express js

Tags: node.js, routes

It might look silly, but I couldn't manage to find a proper answer for it;
I am trying to handle a get request with params in Express js:

```
app.get('/status/:id', function(req, res, next) {

        var par = req.params.id;
    .
    .
    .
        res.render('profile', {xxx: par}); 
    });
```

But the issue is that the resources don't load and I get 404 Error for my static resources.

### Errors:

> GET /status/stylesheets/style.css 404 31.761 ms - 3296 GET
>   /status/stylesheets/customize.css 404 53.355 ms - 3296 GET
>   /status/javascripts/signup.js 404 91.891 ms - 3296 GET
>   /images/Lizofile-white.png 304 0.564 ms - - GET /images/profile.png
>   304 0.769 ms - - GET /images/comment.png 304 0.485 ms - - GET
>   /images/achievements.png 304 0.511 ms - - GET /images/score.png 304
>   0.641 ms - - GET /images/friends.png 304 0.512 ms - - GET /status/stylesheets/style.css 404 24.126 ms - 3296 GET
>   /status/stylesheets/customize.css 404 15.016 ms - 3296 GET
>   /status/javascripts/signup.js 404 16.238 ms - 3296

I can see that the there is a **/status** directory added at the beginning of my resources' path. 
I tried to solve this by amending ***app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));*** but it didn't work.

### app.js

```
> var app = express();
> 
> 
> 
> 
> app.use(session({   secret: 'osjdh018013bashjdas',   resave: false,  
> saveUninitialized: true }));
> 
> 
> 
> view engine setup app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
> app.set('view engine', 'jade');
> 
>
> app.use(logger('dev')); app.use(bodyParser.json()); //pasrse html,
> jason parser app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
> app.use(cookieParser()); app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,
> '/public')));
> 
> app.use('/', index);//home app.use('/login', login);
> app.use('/profile', profile);//user app.use('/register',
> register);//user
> 
> app.use(function(req, res, next) {
> 
>     res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
>     res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
>     res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost");
>     res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
>     next(); });
```

I would appreciate any comments in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are using purely relative references for your static files.

If you have something like this:

```
<link href="stylesheets/style.css">
```

Inside a web page with a URL of:

```
 http://somedomain.com/status/xxx
```

Then, the browser sees your request for `stylesheets/style.css` as a request that should be made relative to the domain and path of the page.  So, it will add `http://somedomain.com/status` onto the front of the requested URL and ask the server for:

```
http://somedomain.com/status/stylesheets/style.css
```

which is not what you want.  If instead, you change your resource references in the page to be only domain relative and not path relative by starting them with a `/`, like this:

```
<link href="/stylesheets/style.css">
```

Then, only the page domain will be added and the browser will request:

```
http://somedomain.com/stylesheets/style.css
```

which should be what your server is expecting.

Comment: Perfect. Works fine now. Thanks.